# How to optimize finding anagrams from a text file in Go

Tags: file, go, anagram

I am trying to solve a coding challenge where one must print all anagrams from a text file matching the input string. Program must execute as fast as possible. Working code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func timeTrack(start time.Time, name string) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("%s took %s", name, elapsed)
}

func SortString(w string) string {
    s := strings.Split(w, "")
    sort.Strings(s)
    return strings.Join(s, "")
}

func FindWord(dict map[string]string, w string) {
    if val, ok := dict[w]; ok {
        fmt.Println("Found anagrams: ", val)
    }
}

func main() {
    defer timeTrack(time.Now(), "factorial")
    file_fullpath := os.Args[1]
    anagram_word := os.Args[2]

    f, err := os.Open(file_fullpath)
    defer f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var txtlines = make(map[string]string)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        k := scanner.Text()
        v := SortString(k)
        txtlines[v] += string(k) + ","
    }

    FindWord(txtlines, SortString(anagram_word))
}
```

Currently, I have it down to about 160ms.

Obviously using an Array would be more efficient than Map, but there is a requirement to print the original word to the console.

Is there some way to improve the efficiency of creating the map?

Comment: Seems it is possible to use arrays, I misunderstood the challenge. Still, my question is still the same, how to read the file line-by-line into an array as fast as possible and also how to set the array as fast as possible?

Comment: It might help to use slice of strings instead of concatenating strings: `var txtlines = make(map[string][]string)`, `txtlines[v]  = append(txtlines[v], k)`.

Comment: You need another file with sorted letters and corresponding words. That would be an optimization.

Comment: imho, you should ask `how to find the slowness in this program and how to fix them`. you should give a data file to work with. my guess, you ll need to strip all the facilities provided by the stdlib to improve performance, the result will worth the ugliness and complexity. later you might ask if the optimized program is the best one to handle 10 rows or 10 trillions of rows.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: peterSO is 10X faster than strom73**.

strom73:

```
$ go build strom73.go && ./strom73 "/usr/share/dict/words" "restful"
Found anagrams:  fluster,restful,
2019/02/26 02:50:47 anagrams took 150.733904ms
$
```

peterSO:

```
$ go build peterso.go && ./peterso "/usr/share/dict/words" "restful"
Found anagrams:  [restful fluster]
2019/02/26 02:50:52 anagrams took 15.093098ms
$
```

---

> How to optimize finding anagrams from a text file in Go
>
> I am trying to solve a coding challenge where one must print all
>   anagrams from a text file matching the input string. Program must
>   execute as fast as possible.
>
> Currently, I have it down to about 160ms.

No test cases are provided.

---

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

---

If we look at [Wikipedia - Anagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) we see: An anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once. Examples, "restful" = "fluster", "funeral" = "real fun", "rail safety" = "fairy tales".

To solve this problem in Go, we use the Go testing package benchmark facility to measure performance. For example, a sum of letter values, a sort of letter values, and the overall algorithm. We relentlessly dissect each line of code for performance. We order the tests for anagrams starting with the cheapest. For example, sorting letters is expensive, so we first check the number of letters, then a simple sum of letters to filter out many non-anagrams cheaply.

We need something to act as an anagram text file. The Linux word dictionary file (`/usr/share/dict/words`) is readily available, although it is limited to single words. It uses upper- and lower-case.

Exhaustive benchmarking is exhausting. The law of dimminishing returns has set in. A ten-fold improvement in speed is good enough for now.

---

`peterso.go:`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func findAnagrams(find string, text io.Reader) []string {
    find = strings.ToLower(find)
    findSum := 0
    findRunes := []rune(find)
    j := 0
    for i, r := range findRunes {
        if r != ' ' {
            findSum += int(r)
            if i != j {
                findRunes[j] = r
            }
            j++
        }
    }
    findRunes = findRunes[:j]
    sort.Slice(findRunes, func(i, j int) bool { return findRunes[i] < findRunes[j] })
    findStr := string(findRunes)

    anagrams := []string{find}
    s := bufio.NewScanner(text)
    for s.Scan() {
        word := strings.ToLower(s.Text())
        wordSum := 0
        wordRunes := []rune(word)
        j := 0
        for i, r := range wordRunes {
            if r != ' ' {
                wordSum += int(r)
                if i != j {
                    wordRunes[j] = r
                }
                j++
            }
        }
        wordRunes = wordRunes[:j]
        if len(wordRunes) != len(findRunes) {
            continue
        }
        if wordSum != findSum {
            continue
        }
        sort.Slice(wordRunes, func(i, j int) bool { return wordRunes[i] < wordRunes[j] })
        if string(wordRunes) == findStr {
            if word != find {
                anagrams = append(anagrams, word)
            }
        }
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return anagrams
}

func timeTrack(start time.Time, name string) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("%s took %s", name, elapsed)
}

func main() {
    defer timeTrack(time.Now(), "anagrams")
    textPath := os.Args[1]
    findWord := os.Args[2]
    text, err := os.Open(textPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer text.Close()
    anagrams := findAnagrams(findWord, text)
    fmt.Println("Found anagrams: ", anagrams)
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of implementing some cases like comparison of word length to filter out the non-anagram words - problem is I'm a beginner in Golang and implementing anytthing takes a lot of time : ). Thank you so much for this. 

Would implementing goroutines improve the performance of anagrams finding? As I understand, IO probably can't be improved - it's limited by read speed and the anagram files are usually less than the default buffer size of bufio (about 1MB?). I'm thinking of implementing goroutines for searching for the anagram match from the dict.

Comment: If you are a beginner with the Go programming language, you should probably use ordinary goroutines from the runtime instead of implementing your own.

Comment: @JesseAmano: Your comment makes no sense. Goroutines are part of the Go programming language. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements. Goroutines are taught as part of A Tour of Go, a first course course for Go progammers. See https://tour.golang.org, in particular https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1.

Comment: @peterSO Yes, goroutines are part of the language, so I recommend using them. Implementing your own would be silly, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JesseAmano: "Implementing your own would be silly, wouldn't it?" Nobody does that! Have you taken A Tour of Go? https://tour.golang.org/